# jplayer full screen

Tags: jquery, jplayer

how can i detect jplayer is on full screen mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, this is how i had to go:

```
  $("a.jp-full-screen").click(function(){

  if($(this).attr("title")=="full screen"){
         $(".hover, ul#navigation").hide()
  }
  })


  $("a.jp-restore-screen").click(function(){
     if($(this).attr("title")=="restore screen"){
         $(".hover, ul#navigation").show()
  }
 })
```

Comment: Thx, I was just looking for this!

Answer (score 6):

The jplayer adds a class of `jp-video-full` to the div when full screen.

You can use that selector for whatever you're trying to achieve.

```
if ($("#jp_container_1").hasClass("jp-video-full")) {
    //do something
} else {
   //do something else
}
```

Comment: And you can customize what class it uses (if you don't like `jp-video-full`)

Comment: Good to know! I just took a quick look at the DOM. :}

Comment: do i need to use something like jquery hasClass?

Comment: You can, What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: to hide a couple of divs if jplayer is fullscreen, i put this in a if statement but does not work:  $("div#jp_container_1").hasClass("jp-video-full")

Comment: I updated my answer, if jplayer is default that should be working. O_o, did you make sure that was the class being added?, as @Milimetric said, you may have customized it.

Comment: yes, no luck,   if($("#jp_container_1").hasClass("jp-video-full")){

    $("ul#navigation").css({"display","none"})
}

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#jp_container_1").status.cssClass == 'jp-video-full') {} else {}
```